# Determine total cost per user from 3 Different Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery

I am working on a theatre booking system in MySql (My first SQL project). I have three tables:

```
Production (contains Title, BasicTicketPrice), 
Performance (PerformanceDate, PerformanceTime, Title) 
Booking (Email of person who booked, PerformanceDate, PerformanceTime, RowNumber).
```

Each person booked tickets for two or three performances (using their email to book).

I need to to write a query which will display the prices paid for all booked seats and I need to output the RowNumber, Email of person who booked and the Calculated Price.

I understand that I need to join these tables and make the query display a temporary column called Calculated Price but I don't know how to calculate the price.

I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.RowNumber, b.Email, pr.BasicTicketPrice 
FROM booking b, production pr performance p
WHERE p.Title=b.PerfDate*b.PerfTime*b.RowNumber;

SELECT CONCAT (PerfDate, PerfTime, RowNumber) AS BookingID FROM booking;

SELECT RowNumber, Email, CONCAT(PerfDate, PerfTime, RowNumber) AS BookingID FROM booking;

SELECT RowNumber, Email, CONCAT((CONCAT(PerfDate, PerfTime, RowNumber) AS BookingID 
   FROM booking)BasicTicketPrice*BookingID);

SELECT RowNumber, Email, CONCAT(PerfDate, PerfTime, RowNumber) AS BookingID INTEGER 
FROM booking;

SELECT RowNumber FROM booking
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Title FROM performance WHERE '2017-11-01 19:00:00' Email IS NULL);
```

But it didn't work.

Any suggestions? I will be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: If a person books 3 tickets, are there three rows in `Booking`, or do you have a `Quantity` column. If not, is `RowNumber` unique per `Performance`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

- One row in Bookings per booked seat
- `Title` to be a suitable primary key for `Production`
- `PerformanceDate, PerformanceTime` to be a suitable primary composite key for `Performance`

You'll be looking to join the three tables together as per the keys assumed above. It seems you wish to group the bookings together per performance, by the person booking the tickets - if so, you'll need to use an aggregate to show the seat numbers (I've used `GROUP_CONCAT` to delimit them), as well as to `COUNT` the tickets purchased and multiply by the ticket cost.

```
SELECT 
   b.Email, prod.Title, per.PerformanceDate, per.PerformanceTime, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(RowNumber) AS BookedSeats, 
   COUNT(RowNumber) * prod.BasicTicketPrice AS TotalCost
FROM Booking b
INNER JOIN Performance per  
     ON b.PerformanceDate = per.PerformanceDate 
        AND b.PerformanceTime = per.PerformanceTime
INNER JOIN Production prod
     ON per.Title = prod.Title
GROUP BY 
   b.Email, prod.Title, per.PerformanceDate, per.PerformanceTime, prod.BasicTicketPrice
ORDER BY prod.Title, per.PerformanceDate, per.PerformanceTime;
```

Technically, we should include all non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`, hence `prod.BasicTicketPrice` is listed as well.

Comment: However, I need to output only the RowNumber, the Email and the TotalPrice. If I take out the prod.Title, per.PerformanceDate and per.PerformanceTime on the second line under SELECT and do the same under GROUP BY and ORDER BY, it doesn't compile. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: A single seat has a single price per performance. Unless the same patron reserves the same seat across multiple performances, your grouping is unlikely to be useful. I assumed a patron would book multiple seats for his friends. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You are correct. Everything is very helpful. I only struggle now because instead of displaying the performance date, time and title, I have to display only the Row Number (the seats basically, the email of the person who booked and the total price for those tickets.

Comment: My bad, I should have been more careful. I realised what I was doing wrong. All good now. Thank you again so so so much for your help. I am truly grateful. All the best to you!